# Testing for Symmetry and Regularity in (Graph-Theoretic) Graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics, combinatorica

I know my way around Mathematica pretty well, however I have not been able to find any built-in functionality for testing a (graph-theoretic) graph for being

- symmetric (arc transitive) – this is the one I need the most
- distance transitive
- distance regular
- strongly regular
- edge transitive
- vertex transitive

(***SymmetricQ*** does **not** test whether or not a graph is symmetric/arc transitive; it "tests if the edges of a given graph represent a symmetric relation".)

(For testing regularity, Mathematica had the function ***RegularQ***, but it became defunct by version 10. It doesn't matter though, regularity is easily tested using the function ***VertexDegree***.)

Where are these functions? Am I not seeing them somewhere? I would find it very disappointing if Mathematica does not have built-in functions for determining these fundamental properties of graphs. If Mathematica doesn't, does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/igraphm-a-mathematica-interface-for-igraph.html)?

Comment: No, I did not. Thank you. That seems to have tests for vertex transitivity and edge transitivity, but I don't see tests for the others. It has the function IGSymmetricQ, but that seems to test for graphs that are both vertex-transitive and edge-transitive, not graphs that are arc-transitive (unfortunately, the word "symmetric" has two different definitions - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_graph).

Comment: If you first turn your undirected graph into a directed graph, with edges going in both directions wherever the original graph had an edge, then `IGSymmetricQ` will use your definition.

Comment: Thank you Sektor and Misha. I will learn this. Graph Theory is outside my primary field but it came up in some research. If either of you want to post your comments as answers I will gladly accept and upvote. Does anyone know about functions that exist for testing the others (strongly regular or distance regular), or would I have to make my own functions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, if we first use `GraphAutomorphismGroup` to find the automorphism group of a graph, it is not hard to figure out if it acts transitively on vertices, edges, arcs, pairs of vertices at distance $k$, or any other objects.

For example, to test if a graph `g` is arc-transitive: test if

```
Complement[Join[EdgeList[g], Reverse /@ EdgeList[g]], 
  PermutationReplace[
    EdgeList[g][[1]], 
    GraphAutomorphismGroup[g]]] == {}
```

To unpack this:

1. `EdgeList[g][[1]]` gives us some edge of the graph `g`. It appears as something like `1<->2`, so it is ordered; it might as well be the list `{1,2}`.
2. Then `PermutationReplace` gives us the orbit of this ordered pair under the action of the group.
3. `Join[EdgeList[g], Reverse /@ EdgeList[g]]` lists all edges of the graph (in both possible orders).
4. `Complement[..., ...] == {}` checks that everything is in the orbit of the edge we picked.

To generalize this, simply replace steps 1 and 3. For step 1, generate a single object of the type you want; for step 3, generate a list of all the objects.

(A tricky detail: when testing for edge-transitive graphs, we should do `Sort /@ PermutationReplace[...]` in step 2, so that we generate every edge in the orbit in its canonical representation.)

This approach covers all the transitivity properties. To test for distance regular and strongly regular graphs, begin with `GraphDistanceMatrix`, and the rest is no longer a graph theory problem.

---

We can also use [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/igraphm-a-mathematica-interface-for-igraph.html), as pointed out in the comments on the question, which tests if a graph is vertex transitive (`IGVertexTransitiveQ`), edge transitive (`IGEdgeTransitiveQ`) and both (`IGSymmetricQ`).

If we test the directed version of a graph for being symmetric, by using

```
IGSymmetricQ[DirectedGraph[g]]
```

rather than simply `IGSymmetricGraphQ[g]`, it will test for arc transitivity, which is just asking if every directed edge can be mapped to every other directed edge.

For large graphs, the igraph approach will be faster than the pure Mathematica code, as pointed out in the comments on this answer.

Comment: You can read the source code of IGraph/M.  `IGVertexTransitiveQ` is a feature unique to IGraph/M, not the igraph core library. It is implemented as `With[{elems = Range@VertexCount[graph]},
    GroupOrbits[PermutationGroup@IGBlissAutomorphismGroup[graph], elems] === {elems}
      ]`.  `PermutationGroup@IGBlissAutomorphismGroup[...]` basically does the same as `GraphAutomorphismGroup`. It uses the Bliss library through igraph. Bliss is much faster than nauty, which Mathematica uses. However, there is a constant overhead in converting the graph to the appropriate format.

Comment: This built-in functions tend to be faster for small graph, but Bliss will usually be (much) faster for large and difficult graphs.

Comment: The `DirectedGraph` function is easier to use for creating bidirectional directed edges.

Comment: The latest release of IGraph/M implements all the properties the OP was asking for. Now it uses C implementations which is likely to be as fast or faster than what you might find in any other package. Any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 8):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) 0.3.111 now has fast functions to test for all of these. Please look under [*Isomorphism -> Properties related to the automorphism group*](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#properties-related-to-the-automorphism-group) in the documentation.

- Regular: `IGRegularQ`
- Vertex transitive: `IGVertexTransitiveQ`.
- Edge transitive: `IGEdgeTransitiveQ`.
- Strongly regular: `IGStronglyRegularQ`.
- Distance regular: `IGDistanceRegularQ`.
- Distance transitive: `IGDistanceTransitiveQ`.
- Arc transitive: `IGEdgeTransitiveQ@DirectedGraph[#]&`. Note that the term *symmetric* is used in different ways by different authors. `IGSymmetricQ` checks if a graph is both vertex and edge transitive. To check for arc transitivity in an undirected graph, first convert it to a directed one using [`DirectedGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirectedGraph.html) then check for edge transitivity.

These are implemented in C++ and are likely to be as fast as any alternatives you might find in any other software package.

---

Here's a table of a few graphs which all have different properties:

[image]

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]

graphs = {StarGraph[4], IGSquareLattice[{2, 3}, "Periodic" -> True], 
   HypercubeGraph[3], GraphData[{"Rook", {4, 4}}], 
   GraphData["ShrikhandeGraph"], GraphData["HoltGraph"], 
   GraphData["Tutte12Cage"], GraphData[{"Paulus", {25, 1}}]};

functions = <|"regular" -> IGRegularQ, 
   "strongly regular" -> IGStronglyRegularQ, 
   "distance regular" -> IGDistanceRegularQ, 
   "vertex transitive" -> IGVertexTransitiveQ, 
   "edge transitive" -> IGEdgeTransitiveQ, 
   "arc transitive" -> IGEdgeTransitiveQ@*DirectedGraph, 
   "distance transitive" -> IGDistanceTransitiveQ|>;

TableForm[
  Through[Values[functions][#]] & /@ graphs, 
  TableHeadings -> {Show[#, ImageSize -> 60] & /@ graphs, Keys[functions]}, 
  TableDirections -> Row
]
```